# Call Javascript function from Rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where you sign in and out from a header in application.html.erb. The signin form (or signout link) calls the users#signIn or users#signout actions respectively. Either action calls redirect_to root_path. That part works.

What I want is to have the header update dynamically instead of refreshing the page (i.e. remove the redirect_to). I want to do that via javascript/jquery (but not coffee). The file views/users/signIn.js contains three functions: one for user signin, one for admin signin, and one for user/admin signout.

I have scoured all over the internet but I cannot find an answer to this. In short, after I signin (or signout) a user or admin, I want to call a javascript/jquery function from users_controller.rb contained in signIn.js (or signIn.js.erb, I'm confused on this).

My code is below. Thank you.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
include UsersHelper
include AdminsHelper
before_action :correctUser, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


...


def signIn
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:user][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        signInUser user
        render js: "sUser();" #Call to javascript function
    else 
        admin = Admin.find_by(email: params[:user][:email].downcase)
        if admin && admin.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
            signInAdmin admin
            render js: "sAdmin();" #call to js function
        else
            flash[:error] = "Invalid email or password"
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end
end

def signout
    #works for both users and admins
    signOutUser
    render js: "signoutAll();" # call to js function
end

private

    def correctUser
        redirect_to root_path unless User.find(params[:id]) == currentUser || adminSignedIn?
    end

    def userParams
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email,
            :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def signInUser(user)
        rememberToken = User.newRememberToken
        cookies[:remember_token] = rememberToken
        #change to cookies.permanent to make cookie stay after browser close
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(rememberToken))
    end

    def signInAdmin(admin)
        rememberToken = Admin.newRememberToken
        cookies[:remember_token] = rememberToken
        #change to cookies.permanent to make cookie stay after browser close
        admin.update_attribute(:remember_token, Admin.digest(rememberToken))
    end

    def signOutUser
        #Works for both users and admins
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end
end
```

views/users/signIn.js

```
function sAdmin() {
    $("#signin").html("Signed in as Admin \
    <%= escape_javascript(link_to currentAdmin.name, currentAdmin)%>. \
    <%= escape_javascript(link_to "Sign Out", signout_path)%>");
}

function sUser(){
    $("#signin").html("Signed in as User \
    <%= escape_javascript(link_to currentUser.name, currentUser)%>. \
    <%= escape_javascript(link_to "Sign Out", signout_path)%>");
}

function signoutAll(){
    $("#signin").html("blah <%= render 'static_pages/form' %>");
}
```

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way, you should have your javascript call an action in a controller that signs the user out or in. Then do what's necessary in your js.

Comment: @Iceman Ok I have the sign in/out functionality firing from the javascript. However, when add some rails code (i.e. "<%= render 'static_pages/form'%>"), it just shows up as plain text. Is this because the javascript is in a .js file and not a .js.erb file? If so, where would I put this .js.erb file? Thanks.

Comment: Ok so I worked around the problem. I still haven't been able to call a function directly, so it's still kinda frustrating.